# Python code runs online but not in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The code below runs fine when I bung it into any online code executor, but in Jupyter notebook where I am writing it I get - 'int' object is not callable (referring to the last line)

1. Surely the code is fine if it runs online?
2. How do I make it work for me?

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return False
    elif x <= 3:
        return True
    elif x % 2 == 0:
        return False
    else:
        for i in range(3, int((x**0.5)+1), 2):
            if x % i == 0:
                return False
        return True

def primecount(ab):
    import itertools
    a,b = ab
    for i in itertools.count():
        n = i*i + i*a + b
        if not is_prime(n):
            return i

ans = max(((a, b) for a in range(-999,1000) for b in range(2,1000)), key=primecount)
```

---> 26 ans = max(((a, b) for a in range(-999,1000) for b in range(2,1000)), key=primecount)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: You probably wrote something like `range = <some int>` or `max  = <some int> `before. Try to restart the kernel, or `del range` or `del max` in this cell. Also, please paste the complete error traceback in your question, so that we don't have to guess.

Comment: Thanks Thierry - del max has worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Because you have imported the itertools in a function called primecount please cut and paste it on the top of the code ( Paste it in the starting of program) and also the range of for loop cannot be defined like this please refer to for loop python3.x

Comment: IDK how this was running online with this mistake.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to `import` in a function, and there is nothing wrong with the way `range` is used here. Also, the OP says that this code runs perfectly, except in his Jupyter notebook. So how could your answer be relevant to the problem here?

Comment: @deoncagadoes There is no mistake in the code, it's perfectly valid, and that's why it ran perfectly for the OP except in his Jupyter notebook. See my comment under the question to see why this happened - that's a common problem in notebooks. This answer here is just plain wrong.

Comment: I have tried your code in Jupiter notebook and it works fine. It returns (-61, 971).

Comment: Seems like an issue with Jupyer installation itself.